# PHP while($roww = $resultt->fetch_assoc()) Stop at the end

Tags: php

Could anyone tell me when my seconds while ends work why the first don't start again ?

```
// Sum of totes for one BFT stations
                $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(ord_Code) FROM `tasiemce`";
                $sqll = "SELECT ord_Code, SSCC FROM `tasiemce`";
                $resultt = $mysqli -> query($sqll);
                $result = $mysqli -> query($sql);

                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    // output data of each row
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                            echo "<div class='button button1'>" . $row["ord_Code"] . "</div>";
                            while($roww = $resultt->fetch_assoc()){
                                if($roww["ord_Code"] == $row["ord_Code"]){
                                    echo "<div class='button button1'>" . $roww["SSCC"] . "</div>";
                                }
                            }
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "0 results";
                }

                $mysqli->close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to rewind $resultt at the end of the first while loop.  This is because after the first iteration of the first while loop, you have already gone through the entire result set of $resultt.

Therefore, the next time you call fetch_assoc on that, it will return NULL since there are no more rows as documented [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

You can seek, or rewind, with the [data_seek](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php) method.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following :-

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(ord_Code) FROM `tasiemce`";
$result = $mysqli -> query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0){
   // output data of each row
   while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
      echo "<div class='button button1'>" . $row["ord_Code"] . "</div>";
      $sqll = "SELECT ord_Code, SSCC FROM `tasiemce` where ord_code = '".$row->ord_code."'";
      $resultt = $mysqli -> query($sqll);
      while($roww = $resultt->fetch_assoc()){
         echo "<div class='button button1'>" . $roww["SSCC"] . "</div>";
      }
   }
}
else{
    echo "0 results";
}
$mysqli->close();
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Did you use the above code ? Or just have given -1 without using it ?

Comment: Please check the above code again and rate my answer again .