# Nested while for table select only giving one result

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to get a list of items from a MySQL query for a drop down list and display the information in another while which delays each row in a table.

it works when i don't use the second while but once added the first select has the results i'm expecting but the following rows are blank.

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Type</td>
        <td>Qty</td> 
        <td>Temp(°C)</td>
        <td>From</td> 
        <td>To</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <?php 
        if ($order_search->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while ($detail = mysqli_fetch_array($order_search)) {
                echo "<td>";
                echo "<select name='type'>";
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($item_search)) {
                    echo "<option>";
                    echo $row[0];
                    echo "</option>";
                }                       
                echo "</select>";
                echo "</td>";                       
                echo "<td>$detail[1]</td>";
                if ($detail[2] > 0) {
                    echo "<td>$detail[2]&deg;C</td>";
                } else {
                    echo "<td>$detail[2]N/A</td>";
                }
                echo "<td>$detail[3]</td>";
                echo "<td>$detail[4]</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>        
            <form method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="entry_id" value="<?php echo $entry_id; ?>">
                <input type='hidden' name='order_id' value="<?php echo $order_id;?>">
                <input type="submit" name="add_equipment" value="Add Equipment">
            </form>     
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Code with the added solution which now works:

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Type</td>
        <td>Qty</td> 
        <td>Temp(°C)</td>
        <td>From</td> 
        <td>To</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <?php 
        if ($order_search->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while ($detail = mysqli_fetch_array($order_search)) {
                echo "<td>";
                echo "<select name='type'>";
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($item_search)) {
                    echo "<option>";
                    echo $row[0];
                    echo "</option>";
                }
                mysqli_data_seek($item_search,0);                       
                echo "</select>";
                echo "</td>";                       
                echo "<td>$detail[1]</td>";
                if ($detail[2] > 0) {
                    echo "<td>$detail[2]&deg;C</td>";
                } else {
                    echo "<td>$detail[2]N/A</td>";
                }
                echo "<td>$detail[3]</td>";
                echo "<td>$detail[4]</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>        
            <form method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="entry_id" value="<?php echo $entry_id; ?>">
                <input type='hidden' name='order_id' value="<?php echo $order_id;?>">
                <input type="submit" name="add_equipment" value="Add Equipment">
            </form>     
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP while($roww = $resultt->fetch\_assoc()) Stop at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50952694/php-whileroww-resultt-fetch-assoc-stop-at-the-end)

Comment: This is the same as the one I just answered above.

Comment: I will have to have a read about this but would it still work with 2 different querys? ive tried placing the data seek just before the second while is this correct?

Comment: Yes, either before, the while, or after it.  Either one should work if you rewind it back to row 0.  Maybe provide an updated code sample underneath showing how you added it.

Comment: Thanks Devon, worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The outer while is not "refreshing" the results in any way; so when it's second iteration occurs, the $item_search results will already be used up.

If you need to use the rows in the result more than once, they should be stored in an array you can iterate over repeatedly.